# MySQL "AS" --- What does it do?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand the functionality of the MySQL "AS" condition; example below.

```
CREATE VIEW `db_name`.`view_name` AS
```

Comment: sorry, wrong duplicate. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: No because when creating a view you use `AS` to define the view

Comment: You may try do your own research and find this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: My question was not about the functionality of `CREATE VIEW`. It was about the `AS` keyword. I have developed a better understanding of it through use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you define the data that the view will aggregate for you.  When you have the following:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT * FROM t;
```

You are creating a view named `v` and you are defining the select statement select it will use to collect data within the view -> `select * FROM t`

This has a lot of good infomration on your question -> [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)